# Rational points on stable curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a strictly henselian local ring of characteristic $0$, we further assume that the residue field $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$ is of positive characteristic. Let $X_K$ be a geometrically connected curve of genus $>1$ over $K=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ admitting a stable model $X\to\mathrm{Spec}R$. I found the following claim:

> **Claim**: Let $Y\to X$ be an etale covering, i.e. a finite etale morphism, and $x\in X_K(K)$. Then the pull-back of $Y\to X$ via $x$ is a trivial etale covering of $\mathrm{Spec}K$.

As an explanation, the author says that this claim is trivially true since $R$ is strictly henselian. I am not sure whether the condition on the existence of a stable model plays some role. But, I think that the claim holds if *any* $K$-rational point of $X_K$ of extends to an $R$-point of $X$. So, here are the questions:

> **Q1**. Does every rational point of $X_K$ extend to $R$-point of $X$? If then, how is the "stable-ness" condition related?
>
> **Q2**. Does the "stable-ness" condition have something to do with the claim? More precisely, if we remove the "stable-ness" condition, does it fail to be true?
>
> **Q3**. If "stable-ness" condition does nothing to do with the claim, i.e. if claim follows only by using "stricly henselian" condition, how can we dervie the claim from the "strictly henselian" condition?

Comment: Could you please clarify your definition of "stable" and also the precise hypotheses on the morphism $Y\to X$?  For every finite etale morphism $\text{Spec}\ L \to \text{Spec}\ K$, e.g., for a finite separable field extension $L/K$, for $Y = \text{Spec}\ L \times_{\text{Spec}\ K} X$ with the second projection to $X$, this morphism is finite and the pullback by $x$ is simply $\text{Spec}\ L \to \text{Spec}\ K$.  In what sense is this etale covering a *trivial* etale covering?  The field $K$ is certainly not separably closed (it does not contain roots of the uniformizing element).

Comment: @JasonStarr At first, $X$ is over $R$. So, I am wondering what you mean by $\mathrm{Spec}L\times_{\mathrm{Spec}K}X$. Also, by "stable" model, I think that the author assumes that $X$ is a stable curve over $\mathrm{Spec}R$ in the sense of Deligne--Mumford such that whose generic fibre is exactly $X_K$.

Comment: I missed that $Y$ is finite and etale over the entire model $X$.  If $X$ is proper over $\text{Spec}\ R$, then every $K$-point of $X_K$ is the generic fiber of a unique $R$-point of $X$, by the valuative criterion of properness.  Since $R$ is strictly Henselian, every finite etale morphism to $\text{Spec}\ R$ is a disjoint union of isomorphisms.

Comment: @JasonStarr Aha, I forgot the valuative criterion of properness which is rather elementary but important. Thank you for recalling it.